# Is it possible to configure SSL for Oracle Database 19c in DB System - Oracle Cloud?

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle19c

I am looking for to enable SSL for Oracle Database 19c in DB System - Oracle Cloud. I could not find any document for it. Is it possible to configure SSL for Oracle Database 19c in DB System - Oracle Cloud?

Comment: Exactly which type of Cloud offering are you inquiring about? Autonomous Database, IaaS, or some other? Which documentation did you consult?

Comment: It is Oracle Cloud (Database Cloud Service Virtual Machine) - https://www.oracle.com/database/vm-cloud.html. The service named: Bare metal, VM, and Exadata under Database catalog name.

Comment: Here is the document: https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Database/Concepts/overview.htm